# C# Change the background color of a textbox on a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a gridview with a `TextBox` in one of the cells on each row. I have a button for each row for entering data. So I know what row I am in. I figured out how to set the background color of the cell, but not the background color of the `TextBox`. Do anyone know how to do this?

`grIndex` - Is the row I am in.

`Cells[]` - is the column the cell is in.

Here is the code I am using to set the cell background color.

```
GridViewListComp.Rows[grIndex].Cells[5].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FindControl` and cast it back to a TextBox to access it's properties.

```
TextBox textbox = GridView1.Rows[grIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
textbox.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Or you could use the `OnRowDataBound` event

```
protected void GridViewListComp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox textbox = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
        textbox.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks for everyone's help.

((TextBox)GridViewListComp.Rows[grIndex].FindControl("txtPolicy")).BackColor = Color.Yellow;